# grep multiples results randomly results in bash

Tags: bash

I'm making a query into a rest api, from this result i got:

```
{ "meta": { "query_time": 0.004266858, "pagination": { "offset": 0, "limit": 00, "total": 4 }, "powered_by": "device-api", "trace_id": "foo" }, "resources": [ "foo/bar", "foo/bar/2", "foo/bar/3", "foo/bar/4" ], "errors": [] }
```

I want to take results only from resources like this:

```
 "resources": [
  "foo/bar",
  "foo/bar/2",
  "foo/bar/3",
  "foo/bar/4"
 ],
```

Can we share some knowledge? thanks a lot!

PS: these results from resources are random

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't use `grep` or other regular expression tools to parse JSON. JSON is structured data and should be processed by a tool designed to read JSON. On the command line [`jq`](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/) is a great tool for this purpose. There are many powerful JSON libraries written in other languages if `jq` isn't what you need.

Once you've extracted the data you care about, you can use the [`shuf`](https://manpages.debian.org/shuf) utility to select random lines, e.g. `shuf -n 5` would sample five random lines from the input.

With the JSON you've provided this appears to do what I think you want:

```
jq --raw-output '.resources[]' | shuf -n 2
```

You may need to tweak the `jq` syntax slightly if the real JSON has a different structure.